# Loading image pixel data gives unexpected result - Python - Pillow

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

Why does image.getdata() return different result second time I invoke it?

```
from PIL import Image

def write():
    image    = Image.open('image.jpg')
    newimage = Image.new(image.mode, image.size)

    pixels   = [p for p in image.getdata()]

    for i in range(100):
        pixels[i] = (255,255,255)
    newimage.putdata(pixels)
    newimage.save('newimage.jpg')

    print(list(newimage.getdata())[0:10])
def read():
    image  = Image.open('newimage.jpg')
    pixels = [p for p in image.getdata()]

    print(list(image.getdata())[0:10])
write()
read()
```

It gives me the following result:
[image]

Why is second set of data differ from the first one?

Comment: `jpg` is a lossy format?

Comment: Consider using NetPBM `PPM` format, or `PNG` format, both of which are lossless.